# Pseudorandom permutation of 60000 elements with a long period

Tags: number-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, random, permutation-cycles

I have a programming assignment that asks me to do mini-batch training. In particular, we are working with the MNIST dataset, which contains 60000 training samples. I would like to figure out the most efficient way to shuffle these images. The idea is to find a bijective hash (or permutation) $H$ on $\{0, 1, \cdots, 59999\}$ such that $X_{\text{shuffled}}[H[i]] = X_{\text{original}}[i]$ effective shuffles the dataset. In other words, $H$ maps the $i$-th element in the original dataset to the $H[i]$-th element in the shuffled dataset. Additionally, the permutation $H$ should have a long cycle, so that I won't get the same order every few shuffles. To clarify, I will do successive shuffles based on the current one, e.g.

\begin{aligned}
X_{\text{shuffled}}[H[i]] =& X_{\text{original}}[i] \\
X_{\text{doubly shuffled}}[H[i]] =& X_{\text{shuffled}}[i] \\
X_{\text{triply shuffled}}[H[i]] =& X_{\text{doubly shuffled}}[i] \\
\cdots
\end{aligned}

By "$H$ should have a long cycle", I mean I don't want to see something like $X_{\text{triply shuffled}} = X_{\text{original}}$.

I [heard](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/array-shuffle-in-cuda/20346/4) that I can let $H[i] = (A \times i) \bmod 60000$, where $A$ is an integer coprime with 60000. I picked $A = 999999000001$ with the hope that such a large prime can give me some randomness, but it just maps everything to themselves

```
>>> np.all(np.array([(999999000001 * i) % 60000 for i in range(60000)]) == np.arange(60000))
True
```

On the other hand, a small $A$ gives a more promising result, but it still does not seem very random

```
>>> np.sum(np.array([(11 * i) % 60000 for i in range(60000)]) == np.arange(60000))
10
>>> [(11 * i) % 60000 for i in range(60000)][-10:]
[59890, 59901, 59912, 59923, 59934, 59945, 59956, 59967, 59978, 59989]
```

There are other methods like doing a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on the indices $0, 1, \cdots, 59999$ and using it as $H$, but I am not sure how that will work since essentially I am calling Fisher-Yates once and use its result successively.

How can I improve the randomness and period of $H$?

---

As a bonus, why is $(A \times i) \bmod 60000$ guaranteed to be bijective when $\operatorname*{GCD}(A, 60000) = 1$? I know nothing about number theory but I am curious.

Comment: Use a random number generator for a random number  (0,1) range.  Multiply by 60000 and keep integer.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That is not necessarily a bijective map, e.g. the 442nd and 9283rd elements may both be mapped to the 481st one, which is undesirable.

Comment: What do you mean by "$H$ should have a long cycle, so that I won't get the same order every few shuffles"? If $H$ is just a permutation of the input indexes, won't you get the same order on every shuffle?

Comment: @Shaun I am not familiar with group theory, but I think permutations form a group or something, and the integers under 60000 are finite so I added the tag. Feel free to edit the tags if you find it irrelevant.

Comment: @Karl I have edit the post to clarify.

Comment: I see, you mean $H$ should have a large [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutation_order). It means something else for a permutation to have a large [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation).

Comment: Search for _generate large random permutation_. Here's one result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357710/efficient-way-to-generate-a-seemingly-random-permutation-from-a-very-large-set-w

Comment: Generate a random permutation $C$ of $1,\dots,n-1$. Then $H(0)=C(1)$; $H(C(i))=C(i+1)$; $H(C(n-1))=0$. $H$ is an $n$-cycle and thus its order is $n$. You could alternatively compose $H$ out of small cycles whose lengths are (powers of) distinct primes, e.g. 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19. Then the order of $H$ is (some multiple of) the product of all the above numbers.